# Remove row which contains specific delimiter with different number of columns

Tags: sed, awk, grep, tr

Want to remove row which contains specific delimiter with different number of columns

```
                                         CPU Load for sdp4

7c:e5:3b:6e:2e:5f:d9:4d:68:4d:d5:57:3a:cb:4d:45.
  02:30PM   up 1 day,   9:20,  2 users,  load average: 6.88, 5.96, 5.57
```

In that case I want to remove everything with delimiter ":" :

7c:e5:3b:6e:2e:5f:d9:4d:68:4d:d5:57:3a:cb:4d:45.

I want remove any kind of this which contains that delimiter.

Expected view:

```
                                         CPU Load for sdp4

  02:30PM   up 1 day,   9:20,  2 users,  load average: 6.88, 5.96, 5.57
```

Comment: But `02:30PM` contains `:`. What is the real problem you're trying to solve here and what have you tried by way of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
grep -v ":..:" yourfile
```

That will remove all lines that contain a pair of colons separated by any two characters - which doesn't seem to appear in the lines that you do want.

Answer (score 1):

try this `grep` line:

```
grep -Pv '^..(:..)+\.$' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "                                         CPU Load for sdp4

7c:e5:3b:6e:2e:5f:d9:4d:68:4d:d5:57:3a:cb:4d:45.
  02:30PM   up 1 day,   9:20,  2 users,  load average: 6.88, 5.96, 5.57"|grep -Pv '^..(:..)+\.$'                                                                                   
                                         CPU Load for sdp4

  02:30PM   up 1 day,   9:20,  2 users,  load average: 6.88, 5.96, 5.57
```